# go get private repo fails due to missing .git when importing from Azure DevOps repositories

Tags: git, go, go-modules

I'm attempting to install a private repository as a golang module.

After reading the Microsoft [blog post](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/go-get?view=azure-devops). I've attempted to do it locally.

I've updated the local .gitconfig with

```
[url "git@ssh.dev.azure.com:v3/<my org>/"]
  insteadOf = https://dev.azure.com/<my org>/
```

Also exported to my environment:

```
export GOPRIVATE=dev.azure.com/<my org>/
```

The repository contains a `go.mod` file with the following header:

```
module dev.azure.com/<my-org>/<project>/<repo>

go 1.18
```

When I attempt to install the module via:

```
go get -v dev.azure.com/<my-org>/<project>/<repo>.git@develop
```

It fails with:

```
go: dev.azure.com/<my-org>/<project>/<repo>.git@v0.0.0-20220827174211-d4e6ad2f92b0: parsing go.mod:
        module declares its path as: dev.azure.com/<my-org>/<project>/<repo>
                but was required as: dev.azure.com/<my-org>/<project>/<repo>.git
```

However, if I remove the `.git` at the end it fails with:

> 203 Non-Authoritative Information

What's the appropriate way of importing private modules

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Removing .git is a first step.

The 203 error is mentioned in [`golang/go` issue 41030](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/41030), which redirects to [issue 28236](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/28236).

It includes:

> If you are here due to authentication issues sync'ing with Azure DevOps repos with `go get`, e.g. on a build machine then you can setup a simple git credential helper in your `gitconfig` file: e.g:
>
> ```
> [credential "https://dev.azure.com"]
>    helper = "/bin/sh /etc/azure-devops-helper.sh"
> ```
>
> with `azure-devops-helper.sh` something like
>
> ```bash
> #!/bin/sh
> echo username=$USERNAME
> echo password=$AZURE_DEVOPS_TOKEN
> ```
>
> where environment variables containing the username and PAT taken.
> This proved more reliable for us than switching to SSH for azure repos.

And, for any `401 Gone` error:

> Needed to tell explicitly in [`GOPRIVATE`](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Configuration_for_downloading_non_public_code) to not to check checksums of `dev.azure.com`.
>
> It seems it was really only that.

Comment: So the solution here is don't do what microsoft says and don't use ssh?

Comment: @August Yes, you can test the [HTTPS option](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/go-get?view=azure-devops#https) from the same doc.